# Puppeteer element click coordinates flakiness

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

This is driving me absolutely crazy. Below is an excerpt from a spec...

```
await page.goto('localhost:5000/settings?disable-sw-cache', {
  waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
});

// doesn't seem to help w/ stopping flakiness
await page.waitFor(2000); 

page.click("[data-puppeteer='reload-configuration-link']");
await page.waitForSelector('.mdc-snackbar.mdc-snackbar--active');

const message = await page.evaluate(
  selector => document.querySelector(selector).textContent,
  '.mdc-snackbar.mdc-snackbar--active'
);

expect(message).to.contain('Successfully reloaded device configuration');
```

This spec passes roughly 4 times out of 6. In the 2 times that it fails, the call to `page.click` is clicking the wrong element. I outputted the coordinates in the click event and they at `30,80` which is competely wrong.

When I logged the coordinates of the element that should be clicked...

```
await page.waitFor(2000); 

// log the current location of the element that is about to be clicked!
const coordinates = await page.evaluate(selector => {
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  const { x, y } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return [x, y];
}, "[data-puppeteer='reload-configuration-link']");

console.log(coordinates)

page.click("[data-puppeteer='reload-configuration-link']");
```

I get `64,194` which is correct, but in the very next line, `page.click` sometimes clicks `30,80` for some reason

Any ideas why these coordinates are wrong 2 out of 6 times?!

---

So I ran my specs w/ `env DEBUG="puppeteer:mouse,puppeteer:keyboard"` to show click debugging and when the spec clicks the wrong element, the debugger outputs the correct coordinates! I'm losing my mind!

Answer (score 2):

Ah! Removing the `isMobile` config prop from the viewport fixes this issue!

```
page.setViewport({
  width: 411,
  height: 731,
  deviceScaleFactor: 2.6,
  isMobile: true, // <---------- REMOVE!
  hasTouch: true,
  isLandscape: false
});
```

I opened this bug report:  https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2465